# How to get the sub process's exit code?

Tags: windows, cmd

Here is a bat script:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM how to get the sub process's exit code

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%i IN (
    `^
        tracert google.com ^
        ^& EXIT /B 5 ^
    `
) DO (
    ECHO [log] %%i
)

REM What i need here is "EXIT_CODE:5" ,
REM but, "EXIT_CODE:0" displayed, help !
REM
REM ***NOTE***: no temporary file or any none-bat style support,
REM             an exact way is welcome, here is bat-zone only.
REM
ECHO EXIT_CODE:%ERRORLEVEL% 

ENDLOCAL

PAUSE
```

I need to capture both the sub process's output and exit code, after which I process the output in a `for...in` statement. The exit code doesn't come through, though:

When the sub process exits, the exit code has either been flushed by the main process after the `for...in` statement finishes or maybe it was never passed in the first place.

Comment: Maybe someone needs disassembling or windbg even ollydbg for solving this question, but i dont known them all. Thank you!

Comment: Disassembling is not required to get the exit code of a program invoked through a batch script. It is part of the standard protocol of a program to return a value when it completes. I've removed the `windbg`, `disassembling` and `ollydbg` tags from this question.

Comment: Win32 debuggers do not work on batch scripts and would be of no use whatsoever.  There's no machine code to disassemble, so that's irrelevant too.

Comment: The command processor does not record the exit code of the implicitly created subprocess used to run the command inside the for statement.  The behaviour you're seeing is as expected.

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Harry, thanks for answer. I wanna the sub process's exit code, and as you said which is implicitly created, because it is in "for...in" statement, but that is the question point here.

Comment: But *why* do you want the subprocess exit code?  In the code you've shown, the exit code is *always* 5, so there's really no point.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I believe he is forcing an error code for testing purposes. But normally he wants the exit code of the command that was executed within the FOR IN() clause.

Comment: @HarryJohnston yeah, exit code is only for question show, i wanna the exit code of the command that was executed within the FOR IN() clause as dbenham said, thank you both, thanks you for your answers.

Answer (score 4):

The commands within a FOR IN() clause are run in a brand new CMD.EXE session, so it is impossible to directly access the ERRORLEVEL or any environment variable that the command(s) may set.

Normally the best and simplest solution is to use a temporary file:

```
yourCommand >output.txt
set exit_code=%errorlevel%
for /f "delims=" %%i in (output.txt) do processOutput
del output.txt
```

But you have stated that you cannot use temporary files.

The only option is to echo the ERRORLEVEL within the IN() clause and then parse the ERRORLEVEL within the DO clause. Echoing the ERRORLEVEL is a bit tricky because %ERRORLEVEL% is expanded at parse time, and the entire IN() clause is parsed at once, so %ERRORLEVEL% will always be 0.

The IN() clause commands are executed with a command line context, not a batch context. The new CMD.EXE session does not inherit the current delayed expansion state - it defaults to delayed expansion disabled. The simplest solution is to use CALL along with a properly escaped `%ERRORLEVEL%` to delay the expansion until after your command has executed. A caret is added to escape for the command context. Then the percents and caret are doubled to escape for the parent batch - `%%^^ERRORLEVEL%%`.

You will want to make your ERRORLEVEL message unique so that your DO clause can distinguish the ERRORLEVEL from normal output.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir DoesNotExist^&call echo ::ERROR::%%^^ERRORLEVEL%%') do (
  set "ln=%%A"
  if "!ln:~0,9!" equ "::ERROR::" (
    set "EXIT_CODE=!LN:~9!"
  ) else (
    REM normal output - do whatever
    echo %%A
  )
)
echo EXIT_CODE=%EXIT_CODE%
```

Here is some sample output of the above

```
C:\test>test.bat
File Not Found
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is EE2C-5A11
 Directory of C:\test
EXIT_CODE=1
```

Comment: dbenham, you are really kind, thank you very much. btw i need a really and exact way to solve this problem, otherwise i will change my mind on bat script, maybe python is a good choice. thank you again, thank you.

Comment: @user1734995: if you're not obliged to use batch scripts, don't!  Depending on context, powershell or vbscript might be preferable to Python (simply because they are built in) but almost anything is preferable to batch.

Answer (score 1):

The exit code of a program can be read through `%ERRORLEVEL%`. To assign it to a variable to `echo` later:

```
set exitstatus=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %exitstatus%
```

You may find [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/09/26/8965755.aspx) by Raymond Chen interesting.

Comment: That does not help with the FOR IN() clause because the command(s) are executed in a brand new CMD.EXE session.

Comment: the link to the article is broken

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Kwan already said: evaluate the `%errorlevel%` variable. Since you seem to want to set the exit code of a sub process, you could do something like this:

```
@echo off

call :trace google.com
echo EXIT_CODE:%errorlevel%

set text=
for /f "delims= tokens=*" %%l in (out.txt) do (
  set text=!text!^

%%l
)
echo !text!

goto end

:trace
tracert %1 >out.txt
exit /b 5

:end
pause
```

**Edit:** Updated with code to read the output into a variable.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I need capture the sub process's output and exit code both, then i have to put the sub process creation logic in "for...in" statement (for output capture), but i can not get the exit code now, so that's the point what i'm asking help here.

Comment: You'll have to redirect the output to a file and read that file into a variable. See my updated answer.